# Cassandra define columns as unic

Tags: cassandra

I think this is no option, but I hope. I need a column in my Cassandra Table with a unic value. It should an autocreated text which I must prove if it is unic. Partition keys are only unic if there is no, aren't they?

What I want to do, is createing a unic columne which is different to partition key. Is there an option to do this?

(What I think I have to do, is to create a seperate table with one key.)

Comment: Do you want a column in the table that only appears once in the whole table, or once in the partition?

Comment: i want a column in whole table where each row has a different value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure unique values in Cassandra is to use a UUID for the value.  If the thing you are creating is time oriented then you should use a TimeUUID.

Comment: Yes, the table has already an uuid, but what i want to add is a unic name to increase readability for searchengines. So i want to create a unic name for url. As refernece i want to use the name, but the name is not unic, so i have to add some informationens if it already exist.

Comment: There is no way in Cassandra to have the database ensure the name is unique.  You can always append a UUID to the end of your string.